# Can't get functions from script tags html

Tags: javascript, html, gasp

Super new to html but i've been trying to get the function TweenTo(elem,dur,style)
from this web script

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

And here is where i'd like to implement that function

```
 <img id="mainPic" src="mainPic.jpg" style="margin-top:70px;position:relative ! important" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" onclick="startAnimation()">
        <script type="text/javascript">
             function startAnimation(){
                 TweenTo(document.getElementById('mainPic'),1,{width:600px})
             }
        </script>
```

I am completely lost here as to why i cant run this function when onClick is called on the picture.
All help is appreciated thanks :D

Comment: because the variable `TweenTo` and `startAnimation` is global. it means you can find it in `window`.

Comment: @chenkehxx so what am I meant to do with my code? Again sorry I'm just literally 3 days into HTML

Comment: um, the dot in `TweenTo.(` is wrong....

Comment: Whay do you have a . after the function call before the parameters?

Comment: @epascarello .... :D thanks ya
It's still not doing the animation though :(

Comment: open up the console, it tells you the errors https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: And I do not think you are using that library right

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation for the library you are using

> https://greensock.com/tweenmax

```
function startAnimation(){
  TweenMax.to(document.getElementById('mainPic'),1,{width:'600px'})
}
```

Comment: YES Thank you so much. Finally getting the hang of this thanks to all you guys

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code: Remove the dot (.) after `TweenTo`. Let it like this:

```
TweenTo(document.getElementById('mainPic'),1,{width:600px})
```

Moreover: Go find in your navigator the "Error console" for javascript, that will help you a lot finding errors.

**Update**

There is another, semantic error in your code: According to the TweenMax.min.js script, the function `tweenTo` begins with a **lowercase**: Pay attention to letter case when programming in javascript.

Comment: Right! ya i just saw another comment on that. But it's still not animating (the Tween Function animates elements)

Comment: LittleSanti and @epascarello ...you guys are amazing :')

Comment: @SaifElkholy epascarello is right in a previous comment: You must learn how to use that library: You must invoke the `tweenTo` function from an object scope: Something like this: `myobject.tweenTo(...)`. Go read the documentation or find an example for what you try to do.